# How to make compiler repeat until the number 0 is presed

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

I'm wondering how to make the compiler repeat itself if the user presses a random button at the end. But if the user presses "0" the compiler exits.

My code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

struct mystruct
{
    float startnummer;
    float hoppnummer;
    float svarighetsgrad;
    float domarpoangs[7];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct mystruct data;
    float max = 0;
    float min = FLT_MAX;
    float sum = 0;
    float avg = 0;
    int i = 0;
    float resultat = 0;

    printf("Startnummer: \n");
    scanf_s("%f", &data.startnummer);

    printf("Hoppnummer:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &data.hoppnummer);

    printf("Svarighetsgrad:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &data.svarighetsgrad);


    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        printf("domarpoang %d\n", i + 1);
        float f;
        if (scanf_s("%f", &f) == 1)
        {
            if (f < min) min = f;
            if (f > max) max = f;

            data.domarpoangs[i] = f;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("error parsing float\n");
            exit(0);
        }

    }

    system("cls");
    printf("Startnummer: %.1f \n", data.startnummer);
    printf("Hoppnummer: %.1f\n", data.hoppnummer);
    printf("Svarighetsgrad: %.1f\n", data.svarighetsgrad);
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        printf("Domarpoang %d: %.1f\n", (i + 1), data.domarpoangs[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        sum += data.domarpoangs[i];

    }
    sum = sum - (max + min);

    avg = sum/5;

    resultat = avg * 3 * data.svarighetsgrad;

    printf("Hoppoang:%.2f \n", resultat);


    printf("Tryck tangent for nytt hopp!"); 
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

*If the user presses random button, the compiler repeat itself from the beginning
*If the user presses 0, the compiler exits.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is this with or without the user pressing enter : `'\n'`?  (Without pressing 'enter' is more challenging.)

Comment: Are you sure you mean the *compiler*, or the *program you make*?

Comment: Oh, and most compilers and computer terminals can handle e.g. Swedish characters such as `'å'`, `'ä'` and `'ö'` in string and character literals. :)

Comment: @chux With pressing 'enter'

Comment: Hint: Always check return value of *scanf* functions, especially when reading numbers.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg C can't handle it. It replaces the Swedish characters with other weird characters..

Comment: Ah yes, the Windows console where you need to have the exact character-set configured or text will be output wrong. I don't know how to set that up though, might want to head over to http://superuser.com/ and ask there for that?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I'll try it. Tack :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer puts a loop around the body of your `main()` code, taking care to re-initialise some of the variables for the next iteration.

There are many SO questions about getting keyboard input and clearing the debris. I know of no *simple standard* ways of testing for keyboard input such as `kbhit()`, for taking a single key input such as `getch()` or for flushing the input. Even `getchar()` is horrible - it won't return until you have pressed "Enter" which it leaves in the input buffer. This has resulted in many SO answers with impenetrable (to me) formats for `scanf()` to flush the input, or testing `if (getchar() == EOF)` - which does not respond to the "Enter" key.

So I have put a simple wrapper around the `main()` code, which terminates when '0' is entered followed by a control char (because `fgets()` appends the `newline`) or terminator. This removes the need to clean up the input - except in the case where the user inputs some silly typing. GIGO!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#define BUFFSIZE 10

struct mystruct {
    float startnummer;
    float hoppnummer;
    float svarighetsgrad;
    float domarpoangs[7];
};

int main(void)
{
    char kbuff [BUFFSIZE+1];
    struct mystruct data;
    float max;
    float min;
    float sum;
    float avg;
    int i;
    float resultat;

    do {
        max = 0;                // initialise for each loop
        min = FLT_MAX;
        sum = 0;
        printf ("Body of your main loop\n");
        fgets(kbuff, BUFFSIZE, stdin);
    } while (kbuff[0] != '0' || kbuff[1] >= ' ');
    return 0;
}
```