# Exit program if user input is 0

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

My program asks the user for inputs. I want it to exit if the first input is zero.

Here is my code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

struct mystruct
{
    float startnummer;
    float hoppnummer;
    float svarighetsgrad;
    float domarpoangs[7];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct mystruct data;
    float max = 0;
    float min = FLT_MAX;
    float sum = 0;
    float avg = 0;
    int i = 0;
    float resultat = 0;

    printf("Startnummer: \n");
    scanf_s("%f", &data.startnummer); //<<---If this i 0 - exit the program
    if (data.startnummer == 0)
    {
        exit;
    }

    printf("Hoppnummer:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &data.hoppnummer);

    printf("Svarighetsgrad:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &data.svarighetsgrad);


    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        printf("domarpoang %d\n", i + 1);
        float f;
        if (scanf_s("%f", &f) == 1)
        {
            if (f < min) min = f;
            if (f > max) max = f;

            data.domarpoangs[i] = f;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("error parsing float\n");
            exit(0);
        }

    }

    system("cls");
    printf("Startnummer: %.1f \n", data.startnummer);
    printf("Hoppnummer: %.1f\n", data.hoppnummer);
    printf("Svarighetsgrad: %.1f\n", data.svarighetsgrad);
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        printf("Domarpoang %d: %.1f\n", (i + 1), data.domarpoangs[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        sum += data.domarpoangs[i];

    }
    sum = sum - (max + min);

    avg = sum/5;

    resultat = avg * 3 * data.svarighetsgrad;

    printf("Hoppoang:%.2f \n", resultat);


    printf("Tryck tangent for nytt hopp!");
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work. I don't get an error but the programs just runs normally without closing when the user's input is 0.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/28285063/440558

Comment: Crank up your compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ehmmm... if you want to shutdown the program write return 0; or whatever value you want your main to return

Answer (score 2):

You must write `exit(0);` (or `exit(SOME_OTHER_INTEGER_STATUS)`), not `exit;`.  Of course, since this is in `main`, you could just write `return 0;` instead.